# FastApi Pydantic - add default value which can be None

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I have a model like this:

```
class RegisterRequest(BaseModel):
    user_firstname: str = Field(default=None, description="Enter your last name")
    user_lastname: str = Field(default=None)
    user_dob: str = Field(default=None)
    user_gender: str = Field(default=None)
    user_about: str = Field(default=None)
```

I would like to provide a typehint to swagger which I was doing from default value – for example `user_firstname` default will be like `"enter username"` its working but if user not pass `user_firstname` it's showing the value entered as `username` so I do that `default = None` which is giving me null but description is not showing in swagger.

[image]

I want description instead of "string" with default value on None

Also tried like this but if I don't pass the value instead of None its getting from schema and showing "Enter your first name"

```
class RegisterRequest(BaseModel):
    user_firstname: Optional[str] = None
    user_lastname: str = Field(default=None)
    user_dob: str = Field(default=None)
    user_gender: str = Field(default=None)
    user_about: str = Field(default=None)

    class Config:
        json_schema_extra = {
            'example': {
                "user_firstname": "Enter your first name",
                "user_lastname": "Enter your first name",
                "user_dob": "Enter your first name",
                "user_gender": "Enter your first name",
                "user_about": "Enter your first name"
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is your endpoint a `post` request type? Perhaps change to a `get` and it will work the way you expect?

Comment: @YaakovBressler yes post because Its have body. And in body I need to add hint with default None because if someone not pass that variable it will show as null which is also working but description not showing there its showing "string". I think it can be done with description but it's not showing description there.

Comment: Have you tried with `Optional[str]` as according to the docs https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/migration/#required-optional-and-nullable-fields

Comment: Otherwise according to the `FastAPI` docs https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body-fields/?h=field#declare-model-attributes you may use `description: str | None = Field(default=None, title="The description of the item", max_length=300)`